# Which database to use instead of mysql (combined with apache, mysql)

Tags: mysql, fractions

We have just begun to think about a new project where it will be crucial to handle fractions of seconds. We will use apache as web server with php.

We will get date data like: 2012-03-31 18:20:10.015493 and want to store it in db.

After some research i noticed that mysql didn't support the fractions before version 5.6 or something. This version seems to be in development stage and therefore I don't want to use it.

What is your recommendation, use another database server or store the date as another data type in mysql ? The demands on another db server is that its compatible with apache and is open source, running on unix.

Anyone got any tips or pointers?

Comment: Compatible with Apache or with PHP?  Also, any research you've done and specific concerns you have should be in your question.  As far as I can tell, you haven't even googled what your other options are.

Comment: Both apache and php.

I have googled, quite much actually, the problem is that i got even more confused after that. That's why i asked it here instead, so i could come with follow ups and discuss.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
Result: 2001-12-23 14:39:53.662522-05
```

See more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: The problem/question is how i store it in database. I know how to handle it in php. One option is as you say, to store it as an big int. But i'm wondering if that could generate problems with calculations and comparison in sql.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer. Previous answer was terrible. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/) (a mysql compatible fork). They support [microseconds](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/microseconds-in-mariadb) in the current stable version (5.3).